# Как получить данные из вложенного массива объектов с сервера? Vue

Tags: javascript, массивы, vue.js, объекты

Я получаю данные с сервера во Vue. Ответ выглядит следующим образом:

```
    {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Носки",
      "slug": "noski",
      "price": 199,
      "colors": [
        {
          "id": 44,
          "color": {
            "id": 20,
            "title": "Red",
            "code": "#dd0808"
          },
          "gallery": [
            {
              "file": {
                "url": "https://vue-moire.skillbox.cc/uploads/file/3/2/4/324e1f4fb34931a1d367602a730a75b5.jpg",
                "name": "324e1f4fb34931a1d367602a730a75b5.jpg",
                "originalName": "Rectangle 121.jpg",
                "extension": "jpg",
                "size": "4.3 Кб"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "seasons": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Осень",
          "code": "autumn",
          "productsCount": 10
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "title": "Весна",
          "code": "spring",
          "productsCount": 10
        }
      ],
      "materials": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Шерсть",
          "code": "wool",
          "productsCount": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Мне необходимо добраться до url изображения. Вот код, с помощью котрого я пытался получить данные по url:

```
data() {
    return {
      productsData: null,
    };
  },

computed: {
    products() {
      return this.productsData ? this.productsData.items : [];
    },
    image() {
      return this.productsData.items.flatMap((item) => {
        return item.colors.flatMap((itemI) => {
          return itemI.gallery.flatMap((itemIm) => {
            return {
              ...itemIm,
              image: itemIm.file.url,
            };
          });
        });
      });
    },
  },
```

Через image() получается вывести изображения, но тогда они выводятся все (некоторые объекты содержат по 2 и более изображения). А мне нужно только первое, которое попадается. Также через нее нет возможности обратиться к **"title"**, **"id"** и **"price"**.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это все уместить в одном computed свойстве или решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

```
image() {
      var images = this.productsData.items.flatMap((item) => {
        return item.colors.flatMap((itemI) => {
          return itemI.gallery.flatMap((itemIm) => {
            return {
              id: item.id,
              title: item.title,
              price: item.price,
              ...itemIm,
              image: itemIm.file.url,
            };
          });
        });
      });
      return images.length ? images[0] : [];
    }
```